# DataTable.Select expression fails using DateTime equals filter

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

I have some data retrieved from a database which I hold in a data table. 
What I want to do is extract only records that have a match to the date passed as a parameter only if it's greater than DateTime.MinValue(). This should be easy.

Below is the code snippet of how I build the query string. I know that if I don't have the date filter I get 'x' records but I always get 0 with the date filter.

```
    string query = string.Format("Field_Name IN( 'GENDER','DOB','MARITAL_STATUS','SS') AND DIFF_TYPE = 'PER' AND Person_ID = '{0}'", Person_ID);

    if (ChangeDetected > DateTime.MinValue)
    {
        query += string.Format(" AND ChangeToDT = #{0}#", ChangeDetected);
    }

    ChangeDataSet.DifferencesRow[] perChanges = this.m_ChangeDS.Differences.Select(query, "ChangeFromDT ASC, Field_Name DESC") as ChangeDataSet.DifferencesRow[];
```

I have tried all sorts of variations on outputting format for the DateTime in the filter but they all have the same result.

I don't know enough LINQ to do the conditional filter that way either. {:o(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try specifying the format directly:

```
query += string.Format(" AND ChangeToDT = #{0}#", ChangeDetected.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));
```

BTW: This has nothing to do with LINQ.

Comment: That worked!!! For some reason the DateTime comparison requires it to be cast to a US formatted string. Thanks.

Comment: BTW, I know this isn't LINQ but a collegue told me it would be easy to do in LINQ... Although he **'Didn't have time'** to show me how to do it.

Comment: I've also notices that the "=" doesn't work so have to do the following: query += string.Format(" AND (ChangeToDT >= #{0}# AND ChangeToDT <= #{1}#)", ChangeDetected.AddMinutes(-1).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm"), ChangeDetected.AddMinutes(1).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm"));

Comment: The `=` works, if `ChangeToDT` is only a date. If it also contains a time, it would be more reasonable to strip it, if you don't care about it.